wrong resolution
A pc I use predominately on Sunday's is one of three connceted to a 43" TV. Today I powered on the PC before the TV and got 800x600 (4:3) with no other options in the drop down menu. 1360x768 (16:9) is what is best. I've tried restarting, xrandr and restarting gdm, no joy. Its a dual boot and windows does just fine. I have installed a Geforce 1030 graphics card. Any suggestions?     TIA  Daryl

Just to confirm, you've run the ubuntu-drivers tool and downloaded the latest NVIDIA drivers that it says are available for your system from the repository?

I was using the latest 550 driver, but checking now it is using X.Org X server. Because it is 460x680 I can't see or activate the apply button in the GUI after selecting the proprietary driver.

I managed to install the latest prop driver via the command line. Joy has returned to my village. Thanks for the nudge.
